# Copying data from one CockroachDB cluster to another

Tags: cockroachdb

I’m looking to copy the data from a production CockroachDB database to a development server. I know that in Postgres, I can directly connect the database servers through `pg_dump` and `psql`. What's the quickest, easiest way of doing this in CockroachDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just create a dump through [`cockroach dump`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/back-up-and-restore-data.html), and then import the SQL file it generates onto the new server:

```
cockroach dump --host=prodhost dbname > backup.sql
cockroach sql --host=devhost -e 'CREATE DATABASE dbname'
cockroach sql --host=devhost --database=dbname < backupsql
```

If all you really care to copy is the database's schema (e.g. if you’re moving from dev to production), you can do so by adding the `--dump-mode=schema` option to the `cockroach dump` command.

Comment: dump has been deprecated from 21.2 and would require us to copy to a centralized storage like s3 and restore from there.

Comment: Since the I wrote my original answer, full-cluster backup has been made free to use without a license: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/backup.html

I expect that'd be the recommended approach now. If you really don't want to use cloud storage, you can set up a local file server to write the backup to: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/use-a-local-file-server-for-bulk-operations

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree, basically NFS, S3, Azure or some sort of central storage is required with latest developments.

Comment: According to docs, HTTP storage is disabled for BACKUP command. no option for local file export, no support for HTTP, only cloud providers. seems like huge lack of functionality that leads to not use cockroach but postgres.

Answer (score 0):

As of Cockroachdb v22.2.9, you could do:

```
backup database db_test into 'nodelocal://self/db_test';
restore database db_test from latest in 'nodelocal://self/db_test' WITH new_db_name = 'db_test_new';
```

Be mindful on the backup paths since this had to be cleaned up if you're taking frequent Full backups.

```
show backups in 'nodelocal://self/db_test';
```

Alternatively, the `nodelocal` could be replaced with s3 path and you can setup an auto-delete config on old backups for s3. That's one idea to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same challenge while trying to clone a production cluster to staging. Production and staging clusters running on CockroachDB Serverless. I used the backup and restore approach with S3 as storage for the backup. If it's OK for you to create an S3 bucket and get AWS keys with read/write access to this bucket, I'd recommend this method. Below is quick script to achieve this.

```
SOURCE_HOST="***"
SOURCE_PORT="26257"
SOURCE_USER="***"

TARGET_HOST="***"
TARGET_PORT="26257"
TARGET_USER="***"

BACKUP_S3_BUCKET="***"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="***"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="***"

PATH_TO_CERTS_DIRECTORY="***"

cockroach sql \
  --host "$SOURCE_HOST" --port "$SOURCE_PORT" \
  --user "$SOURCE_USER" \
  --certs-dir="$PATH_TO_CERTS_DIRECTORY" \
  --execute "BACKUP INTO 's3://$BACKUP_S3_BUCKET?AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID&AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY' AS OF SYSTEM TIME '-10s';"

cockroach sql \
  --host "$TARGET_HOST" --port "$TARGET_PORT" \
  --user "$TARGET_USER" \
  --certs-dir "$PATH_TO_CERTS_DIRECTORY" \
  --execute "RESTORE FROM LATEST IN 's3://$BACKUP_S3_BUCKET?AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID&AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY';"
```

If you want to restore the backup into a local environment, running on a CockroachDB Docker container, and you know it's fine in your scenario, you can use the command below:

```
cockroach sql \
  --host "$TARGET_HOST" --port "$TARGET_PORT" \
  --user "$TARGET_USER" \
  --insecure \
  --execute "RESTORE FROM LATEST IN 's3://$BACKUP_S3_BUCKET?AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID&AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY';"
```